# SELECT a record by the MAXIMUM of another column and another record by a binary variable in a GROUP BY statement - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to retrieve the dominant payment description of an account based on the maximum value of its payment and its rate based on an indicator variable called Rate_Include in SQL Server. As I am relatively new to SQL Server, I wonder if anyone can help me about this query. I tried using having and inner join, but this issue is a bit more complicated.

This is for SSMS Studio 17. The table is called `Payment`.

The original table is listed as follows.

[image: Payment]

Expected Output:

[image: Aggregated Results]

Comment: Also please post some sample data that can be copy and pasted out, and uses temp tables or table variables (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56157876/sql-get-rows-that-has-same-created-date-datetime-till-minutes/56158067#56158067).

Comment: @David. please explain what is the value of every column.

Answer (score 0):

The following Query will be helpfull.

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER, SUM(Payment_Amount)  Payment_Amount, '' Dominant_Payment, 0.00 
Rate, MAX(Payment_Amount) MaxPayment
INTO #PAYMENTS
FROM Payments
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER

--Updating Dominant_Payment
UPDATE TP  SET Dominant_Payment = P.Payment_Description
FROM Payments P 
JOIN #PAYMENTS TP ON P.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = TP.ACCOUNT_NUMBER AND P.Payment_Amount = 
TP.MaxPayment
--Updating Rate
UPDATE TP  SET Rate = P.Rate
FROM Payments P 
JOIN #PAYMENTS TP ON P.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = TP.ACCOUNT_NUMBER AND P.Rate_Include = 'Y'

SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER, Payment_Amount, Dominant_Payment, Rate
FROM #PAYMENTS

DROP TABLE #PAYMENTS
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish this task. for readability purposes, subqueries are very simple to understand. I have broken it up for you.

Please note this was very quickly written and is not optimized. I will suggest you do further research into JOINS and subqueries and maybe try different approaches.

```
            SELECT p.Account_Number,
                   SUM(p.Payment_Amount) AS Payment_Amount,
                   sub2.Payment_Description,
                   sub3.Rate
            FROM Payment p

            JOIN (SELECT Account_Number,
                              MAX(Payment_Amount) AS Payment_Amount
                       FROM Payment
                       GROUP BY Account_Number) sub ON p.Account_Number = sub.Account_Number

            JOIN (SELECT Account_Number,
                              Payment_Amount,
                              Payment_Description
                       FROM Payment) sub2 ON sub.Account_Number = sub2.Account_Number AND sub.Payment_Amount = sub2.Payment_Amount

            JOIN (SELECT Account_Number,
                              MAX(Rate) AS Rate
                       FROM Payment WHERE Rate_Included = 'Y'
                       GROUP BY Account_Number) sub3 ON sub.Account_Number = sub3.Account_Number

            GROUP BY p.Account_Number,
                     Sub2.Payment_Description,
                     sub3.Rate
```